# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.resolveTemplate() using jaxrs cxf implementation

Tags: java, web-services, rest, maven, jax-rs

I am creating `REST` client using `jaxrs api` with `jaxrs-cfx` implementation.

I am using `Maven` Build tool for dependency management which is like this :-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs-client</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>swagger-jaxrs-client</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!--plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <webApp>
            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
          </webApp>
          <webAppSourceDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</webAppSourceDirectory>
          <stopPort>8079</stopPort>
          <stopKey>stopit</stopKey>
          <httpConnector>
            <port></port>
            <idleTimeout>60000</idleTimeout>
          </httpConnector>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
              <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/gen/java</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <version>${swagger-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback-version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>${logback-version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- CXF Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

     <!-- CXF server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-wsdl</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <swagger-core-version>1.5.9</swagger-core-version>
    <jetty-version>9.2.9.v20150224</jetty-version>
    <jersey2-version>2.22.2</jersey2-version>
    <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
    <logback-version>1.1.7</logback-version>
    <servlet-api-version>2.5</servlet-api-version>
    <cxf-version>3.1.6</cxf-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

and my client program is like this :-

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

public class PsbClientJAXRS_GET {


    private final static String RESOURCE_URI = "http://localhost:2525/psb";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

        Client client = null;

        WebTarget webTarget = null;

        client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        webTarget = client.target(RESOURCE_URI).path("/add-psbdata");
        webTarget = webTarget.path("/{name}").resolveTemplate("name", "Ram").path("/{id}").resolveTemplate("id", 101);

        Response response = webTarget.request().get();


        if(response.getStatus() == Status.OK.getStatusCode()){
            System.out.println("Data Passed Successfully ..... & status code is " + response.getStatus());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Failed to hit the server. ");
        }

    }

}
```

but when I am using resolveTemplate() method I am getting the error as :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.resolveTemplate(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl$WebTargetImpl.resolveTemplate(ClientImpl.java:403)
>     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl$WebTargetImpl.resolveTemplate(ClientImpl.java:396)
>     at com.jaxrs.test.PsbClientJAXRS_GET.main(PsbClientJAXRS_GET.java:37)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.resolveTemplate(String, object)` is available since JAX-RS 2.0. [See](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#resolveTemplate-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

Some of your dependencies have included the JAX-RS 1.0 jars. `swagger-jaxrs` uses it. Change the artifact name to `swagger-jersey2-jaxrs` [See documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup). You may want to review the others dependencies and the code to see if this change could affect anything